# Retrieve order details after order is placed in craft commerce

Tags: php, e-commerce, craftcms

so I have added this code below inside `Module.php` and the purpose is to get specific order details and pass them to a trustpilot script code which is also pasted below. I am not sure what data $order variable will return so I did a dd() on that variable. But problem is, I am not allowed to place test orders. So can someone tell me how do I get email,  full name & order id from $order variable and pass them to the trustpilot javascript ?

```php
Event::on(
    Order::class,
    Order::EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER,
    function(Event $event) {
        // @var Order $order
        $order = $event->sender;
        Craft::dd($order);
    }
);
```

Trustpilot script:

```js
<script> 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const trustpilot_invitation = {
               recipientEmail: 'john@gmail.com',
               recipientName: 'John',
               referenceId: 'Order_123',
               source: 'InvitationScript',
          };
          tp('createInvitation', trustpilot_invitation);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to check the [Craft Commerce API](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v2) as a reference but these should do the trick for you.

```
$order->reference
$order->email
```

With first and last names there are two possible ways to get these.
Either from the User assigned to the Order (if any) or from the Customer assigned to the order (if any as people can be guests). Note if you want to get these details from the customer you'll have to get it from the primary address - try to just use the User if possible... much easier.

e.g.

```
$order->user->firstName
```